# Working with TFS source control folders without map to local folder

Tags: tfs, alm

I have many projects in my Source Control folder, can I work from the server repository without mapping a local folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can configure you local workspace to only map to the folders you are interested in. You can also create more that one workspace.

For example:

1. Create workspace called "Project A"
2. Create a Mapping from `$/TeamProject/Stuff/MoreStuff/ProjectA` to `C:\Code\ProjectA`

Repeat for other projects you are interested in.

You can now select a workspace to use in Source Control Explorer (and in Pending Changes). When you do a "Get Latest" on your workspace you will only get files you have mapped.